# How to formally reject a SOAP request?

Tags: soap

I've a large F5 LTM load balancer environment I'm looking after which we are configuring to rate limit requests at a URI level. For human web users we are 302ing them to a busy page, but we also run web services and need to politely tell the soap client to go forth and procreate as well. Not knowing a whole heap about SOAP/XML responses I'm not clear on what we should tell the client. Will a very basic 500 reponse suffice or do we need to craft an legit SOAP response as well?

Comment: This really depends on how the client deals with the 5xx series message (some will look at the body and handle it as a response, others won't).  To be safe, [do as wallenborn suggests](http://serverfault.com/a/349202/32986) and return the SOAP Fault message as the body of your 5xx error.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine your 500 with a [SOAP Fault](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383507) message, which allows your clients wrap their request into a try/catch (or whatever their language's mechanism is for dealing with this) and receive a polite "please come back later" message in the caught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why not send an http 503 or 509 status?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: well I meant 503 actaully, not 500, my bad. But It was whether the XML content is relevant or we can happily just leave it at a 503 and forget abuot it?